# Rails 4 - Uninitialized constant Mongo Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mongohq

I am attempting to setup MongoHQ using Heroku and rails 4. I have everything setup correctly to my knowledge, but I'm now getting this error:

`uninitialized constant Job::TempEmailContactStoreCsv`

This is the `Job` model where error is happening:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def store_email_contact_csv(file)
    contact_array = csv_to_array(file)
    TempEmailContactStoreCsv.create(email_contact_array: contact_array, job_id: id)
  end

end
```

And my mongo model:

```
class TempEmailContactStoreCsv
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email_contact_array, type: Array
  field :job_id

  def self.store(job_id, email_contact_array)
    r = TempEmailContactStoreCsv.find_by(job_id: job_id)
    if (r.nil?)
      TempEmailContactStoreCsv.create!(job_id: job_id, email_contact_array: email_contact_array)
    end
  end

  def self.exists?(job_id)
    r = TempEmailContactStoreCsv.find_by(job_id: job_id)
    return r.nil? == false
  end

  def self.retrieve(job_id)
    return TempEmailContactStoreCsv.find_by(job_id: job_id)
  end

  def self.delete(job_id)
    r = TempEmailContactStoreCsv.find_by(job_id: job_id)
    r.destroy unless r.nil?
  end

end
```

So it seems that my mongo model is not being initialized, and the namespacing seems weird to me also.

Any thoughts as to what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Where on disk is TempEmailContactStoreCsv? If it wasn't where rails expects to find it that would explain things.

Comment: Good point - It is located at app/models/temp_email_store_csv.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rails to load a class automatically, the file must be within rails load path (which includes app/models so you are fine there) and the file name should be the camelcased version of the class name.

In your case the file name should be `temp_email_contact_store_csv.rb` not `temp_email_store_csv.rb`